# onpopstate returning data twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, url

I've started to play around with onpopstate but ran into a problem. Whenever I click the back button on my browser, the url does change accordingly but the page code is loaded twice so I receive two lists and two div's. Why is is it producing double the code and how do I fix it? The sample code is below.

```
<style type="text/css">

div {width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid;}

</style>

<ul>

   <li class="sour">

   <input type="button" value="1"/>

   </li>

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" >


$('ul li:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
var url = $(this).index();  
$('#insert').load('1.php');
window.history.pushState('', '', 'test1.php?challenge=' + url);
e.preventDefault();
});


window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  $('#insert').load(location.pathname); 
};

</script>


<div id="insert">

<p>hello there</p>

</div>
```

Here is the contents of 1.php

```
<p>first file</p>
```

Here is a link to some screenshots I took of what visually happens. The first image is when I first load the screen. the second image is what happens when I press the button 1. The third image is what happens when I click back on my browser.

http://imgur.com/Nsqej,E1Ydc,sFCLl#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the problem sequence you describe, `onpopstate` will load the contents of `test1.php` into the `#insert` div. Since the landing page was also `test1.php` this will result in the duplication seen in your screenshots.

You could make this someone else's problem by using [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). If you're not tied to jquery there are also other solutions out there that are probably easier than rolling your own.

Comment: Although it will take some time pjax is what I found to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have included the jQuery library twice somewhere.

Comment: Nope. It's only listed once in the main file and not listed at all in 1.php